# Direct JavaScript call inside XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I thought I had a simple code inside an XMLHttpRequest:

```
if() {
    echo "<img src=\"images/ok.png\" />";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            blockInput('conj0');
          </script>";
}
```

But the JS - a simple function ddisabling the input field - just won't work. It does though when I put it in the original HTML code (so not via JS/XHR), or when I call it with an event (even from inside the XHR):

```
echo "<img src=\"images/ok.png\" onMouseOver=\"blockInput('conj0');\" />";
```

but doesn't when it's called directly.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You don't provide enough information. How are you processing the response? How are you inserting the HTML into the page? `<script>` elements added via `innerHTML` are not evaluated.

Comment: Ahh, that's the answer then, thank you so much.
I indeed use innerHTML (document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; and the usual stuff before and after)
Thanks again